# Auto Increment Not Working On MySQL & PHP. I've set th code properly but not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've set id to AUTO_INCREMENT but code is not working. Can anyone help me with that?
I've tried multiple things like NULL, DEFAULT, ''
I'm using it in a php variable like

```
$x="INSERT INTO information (id, username)  
VALUES ('', 'something')";
```

Help me in this. Thank You

```
INSERT INTO information (id, username)  
VALUES ('', 'something');
```

Comment: Assuming your `id` column is the one with the autoincrement, simply omit it from your query. `INSERT INTO information (username) VALUES ('something');`

Comment: I'm getting an error "Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1"

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Comment: Yes here please.
https://i.imgur.com/5zUWXOk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement is specifically attempting to set the ID column, so AUTO_INCREMENT won't work. Additionally, you're setting it to an empty string when the column requires an integer, so you're seeing the error message you posted.

To use an AUTO_INCREMENT column, omit it from your INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO information (username)  VALUES ('something');
```